# ubercart - Add sku to a product catalog title via tokenizing it or adding it to a view?

Tags: views, 6, ubercart

I'm looking to add the sku in the product catalog view.

Thus producing this:

`[title][sku]`

Is there a way to tokenize it? I've looked around each field. It seems as the sku is not exposed in views as a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see SKU in views, see the screenshot below, so not sure if I'm missing something obvious about the question.

[image]

Comment: Are you using D6? UC2.4 ?

Comment: D6.22, UC 6.x-2.6, Views 6.x-2.12.

Comment: Ah i have to add the field for it to tokenize. Thanks.